# Unable to use Paypal API on an SSL website

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have an SSL website with Paypal API integration using cURL.

This is my class on PHP includes file:

```
class paypalApi {
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $signature;

    function post($method, $params, $mode) {
            // Method: Required
            // Parameters: An array containing the requested parameters

            // The request URL
            $url = "https://api-3t".$mode.".paypal.com/nvp";

            // Version of the API
            $version = '116.0';

            // Construct the query params
            // Set the API method, version, and API credentials.
            $credentials = array('METHOD' => $method, 'VERSION' => $version, 'USER' => $this->username, 'PWD' => $this->password, 'SIGNATURE' => $this->signature);
            $params = array_merge($credentials, $params);

            // Set the curl parameters.
            if(function_exists('curl_exec')) {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

                // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

                $response = curl_exec($ch);
            }

            if(empty($response)) {
                $opts = array('http' =>
                    array(
                        'protocol_version' => '1.1',
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'content' => http_build_query($params)
                    )
                );
                $context = stream_context_create($opts);
                $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            }
            // Parse the response
            parse_str($response, $responseArr);

            // If the request fails
            if(empty($responseArr) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $responseArr)) {
                global $LNG;
                // Mimic a fake response
                return array('L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => $LNG['error'], 'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => $LNG['payment_error_0'], 'ACK' => 'REQUEST_FAILED');
            }
        return $responseArr;
    }
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work, clicking on the pay button brings the user to Paypal but after finishing the process it brings back the user to the website, the url seems correct (ex. `https://example.com/pro&type=successful?token=EC-8BB04791XJ708490K&PayerID=QL54Q696KZCLA`) but without make the payment.

I tried the sandbox too, but I can't see any error on Apache log file so I need to debug `$response`, for this reason I tried adding `echo var_dump($response);` before parse the response.

But I don't have much experience on debugging, and on Chrome I don't know where to check the response.(on JS console I can't see it)

How could I debug this API response to check why paypal doesn't allow payments for my website? (the website is already verified)

**UPDATE**

As authentication I'm using the API signature NVP format with `SetExpressCheckout` method.

This is the code for my response:

```
        // Execute SetExpressCheckOut method to create the payment token and PayerID
        $paypalResponse = $paypal->post('SetExpressCheckout', $params, $PayPalMode);

        //Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
        if(strtoupper($paypalResponse["ACK"]) == "SUCCESS") {
            // Generat the PayPal payment url with the response Token
            $paypalurl = 'https://www'.$PayPalMode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$paypalResponse["TOKEN"].'';

            // Redirect to PayPal payment page
            header('Location: '.$paypalurl);

            // Execute DoExpressCheckoutPayment to receive the payment from the user
            $paypalResponse = $paypal->post('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $params, $PayPalMode);

            // Check if the payment was successful
            if(strtoupper($paypalResponse["ACK"]) == "SUCCESS") {


                // Verify if the payment is Completed
                if($paypalResponse["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"] == 'Completed') {
                    // Execute GetExpressCheckoutDetails to retrieve the transaction details
                    $params = array('TOKEN' => $token);

                    $paypalResponse = $paypal->post('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $params, $PayPalMode);

                    // If the GetExpressCheckoutDetails was successful
                    if(strtoupper($paypalResponse["ACK"]) == "SUCCESS") {
                        $date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime(($_SESSION['SelectedPlan'] == 1 ? "+1 year" : "+1 month")));

                        $stmt = $db->prepare(sprintf("INSERT INTO `payments`
                            (`by`, `payer_id`, `payer_first_name`, `payer_last_name`, `payer_email`, `payer_country`, `txn_id`, `amount`, `currency`, `type`, `status`, `valid`, `time`) VALUES 
                            ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                            $db->real_escape_string($feed->id), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['PAYERID']), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['FIRSTNAME']), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['LASTNAME']), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['EMAIL']), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME']), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID']), $db->real_escape_string($paypalResponse['AMT']), $settings['currency'], $_SESSION['SelectedPlan'], 1, $date, date("Y-m-d H:m:s")));

                        // Execute the statement
                        $stmt->execute();

                        // Check the affected rows
                        $affected = $stmt->affected_rows;

                        // Close the statement
                        $stmt->close();

                        // If the pro status has been added
                        if($affected) {
                            // Set the pro account to valid
                            $proAccount = 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $TMPL['error'] = notificationBox('error', '<strong>'.urldecode($paypalResponse['L_SHORTMESSAGE0'].'</strong>: '.$paypalResponse['L_LONGMESSAGE0']));
                    }
                } else {
                    $TMPL['error'] = notificationBox('error', '<strong>'.urldecode($paypalResponse['L_SHORTMESSAGE0'].'</strong>: '.$paypalResponse['L_LONGMESSAGE0']));
                }
            } else {
                $TMPL['error'] = notificationBox('error', '<strong>'.urldecode($paypalResponse['L_SHORTMESSAGE0'].'</strong>: '.$paypalResponse['L_LONGMESSAGE0']));
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

This is my error.log file:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 173.0.82.83...
* Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using ***********************
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
*        start date: 2015-09-16 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-10-31 23:59:59 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 862
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
* upload completely sent off: 862 out of 862 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 09:49:59 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: SetExpressCheckout
< X-PAYPAL-API-RC: 
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 138
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 7d9949c818525
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D3349709654; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
* Closing connection 0
```

**2nd EDIT**

Finally I was able to debug the response (there was a redirection problem)

```
TOKEN=EC-9F8624569H0752611
BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS=0
CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionCompleted
TIMESTAMP=2015-12-30T15:41:54Z
CORRELATIONID=19204729b140
ACK=Success
VERSION=116.0
BUILD=18308778
EMAIL=info-buyer@example.org
PAYERID=QL54Q696KZCLA
PAYERSTATUS=verified
FIRSTNAME=test
LASTNAME=buyer
COUNTRYCODE=IT
SHIPTONAME=test buyer
SHIPTOSTREET=Via Unit? d\'Italia, 5783296
SHIPTOCITY=Napoli
SHIPTOSTATE=NAPOLI
SHIPTOZIP=80127
SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=IT
SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME=Italy
ADDRESSSTATUS=Unconfirmed
CURRENCYCODE=EUR
AMT=4.00
ITEMAMT=4.00
SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
HANDLINGAMT=0.00
TAXAMT=0.00
INSURANCEAMT=0.00
SHIPDISCAMT=0.00
L_NAME0=Monthly Pro Plan - example subdirectory
L_NUMBER0=cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da
L_QTY0=1
L_TAXAMT0=0.00
L_AMT0=4.00
L_DESC0=Monthly Pro Plan - example subdirectory
L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0= 0.00000
L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0= 0.00000
L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0= 0.00000
L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0= 0.00000
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=4.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=4.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID=61M42051UB346361T
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=false
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=test buyer
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=Via Unit? d\'Italia, 5783296
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=Napoli
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=NAPOLI
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=80127
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=IT
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME=Italy
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS=Unconfirmed
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS=None
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Monthly Pro Plan - example subdirectory
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=0.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=4.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Monthly Pro Plan - example subdirectory
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0= 0.00000
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0= 0.00000
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0= 0.00000
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0= 0.00000
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID=61M42051UB346361T
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE=0
```

So, from my side everything works right now, but I see no transactions on sandbox Paypal. What's wrong?

Comment: Which API call (method) are you working with?  Can you post a sample of the raw request and response that is getting generated from this?

Comment: That doesn't look like the REST API, and that's not the RAW request I was asking for.  This is the code that generates the request.  Need to see the actual request.  Also, as a side note, when checking the status of ACK simply looking for Success won't work.  You could get SuccessWithWarning, which means it worked but had a warning, but then your code would treat that as a failure.

Comment: @AndrewAngell my request is for the API signature...I created a sandbox account and on my application I set "sandbox mode on" and I inserted the Business Profile API Credentials (Username Password Signature). Changing my source with `SuccessWithWarning` I'm not able to go further from my webpage (it doesn't go to Paypal), of course no errors from console, only an empty bootstrap warning box after press the buy button.

Comment: @AndrewAngell ...and of course I'm using the NVP format with API signature

Comment: You still haven't provided the raw request and response getting generating from your code.

Comment: Your code seems a little out of place, too.  The correct order of the calls is SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and then DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  It looks like you're calling DECP before you're calling GECD..??

Comment: @AndrewAngell I tried adding `echo var_dump($response);` before parse the response, but I don't see anywhere the echo output. I tried also what you suggested and I placed  DoExpressCheckoutPayment after the GetExpressCheckoutDetails but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you know which call is failing?  Is it failing right away with SetExpressCheckout?

Comment: @AndrewAngell I know for sure there is something wrong with the API response, for this reason I need to debugging the API by outputting the API response. My cURL seems to be working (I checked my error log file)

Comment: Ok, then post a sample of the raw response you're getting.  That's all I've been asking for this whole time.  Gotta help me help you, man.  ;)

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is just using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead of what you're using.  It has everything already prepared for you and it's working out of the box.  [Here is the sample](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/SetExpressCheckout.php) that comes with it, and you'll see you can get all the way through the whole process error free.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I have not that raw response since I'm unable to output...I added `echo var_dump($response);` in my class, but where I supposed to view the echo? I know it's a dumb question but I can't see in console nor in my error.log file. And thanks for your link

Comment: Can you post the NVP call you're making any the raw response you get? (minus your credentials). The PHP code isn't terribly useful for this

Comment: @Machavity sorry but how can I get those response? From access.log?

Comment: @Simone No, get it from your CURL request. Specifically `$response = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: @Machavity as I wrote before I added `echo var_dump($response);` in my class before this comment `// Parse the response`...however I don't know where to check the echo.

Comment: @Simone Have you thought about writing the calls and responses into your database? Without the calls to PayPal, diagnosing your issue here is going to be difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: check out dis link http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration hope it helps

Comment: @Machavity I tried this `$this->db->query("INSERT INTO reports (message) VALUES ('{$this->db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($response))}')");` and got 500 internal server error

Comment: @youngdero thanks for the link...but everything I have is already setup correctly, the only thing that makes me mad is the inability to debug `$response` because there is something wrong with the API call

Comment: let me know what is the print by this code: print('<pre>'); print_r($paypalResponse); print('</pre>');exit;. You need to put this code after calling `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`.

Comment: @Machavity I updated my question, I finally get the response, there was a redirection problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your process seems highly convoluted. Let's break this down

```
// Execute SetExpressCheckOut method to create the payment token and PayerID
$paypalResponse = $paypal->post('SetExpressCheckout', $params, $PayPalMode);

    //Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
    if(strtoupper($paypalResponse["ACK"]) == "SUCCESS") {
        // Generat the PayPal payment url with the response Token
        $paypalurl = 'https://www'.$PayPalMode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$paypalResponse["TOKEN"].'';

        // Redirect to PayPal payment page
        header('Location: '.$paypalurl);
```

So far so good. You do your SEC call, get your token and pass the user on to PayPal. But then this next part is confusing

```
// Execute DoExpressCheckoutPayment to receive the payment from the user
$paypalResponse = $paypal->post('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $params, $PayPalMode);

// Check if the payment was successful
if(strtoupper($paypalResponse["ACK"]) == "SUCCESS") {
```

This doesn't make any sense. You just bounced the user to PayPal with `header` and we're calling this with what appears the be the same data we passed to the SEC call. `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` requires you pass back the token and the user just left the site to authorize it. I would expect to see your code look for `$_GET['TOKEN']` (meaning the user returned from PayPal) and then build a **new** request for that. Right now, as your code is written, it's just chaining all 3 calls in one giant chain.

Here's what the process should look like

- `SetExpressCheckout` - Bounce user to PayPal. Stop processing
- `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` - User has returned from PayPal because we have a TOKEN in the query string. Running this call now lets us make sure the TOKEN is valid
- `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` - If the TOKEN is valid, let's complete the sale.

Last but not least, you can't just look for **Success**. [Read the docs on ACK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/). You can also get **SuccessWithWarning**. Change your success condition to

```
 if(stripos($paypalResponse["ACK"], "SUCCESS") !== false) {
```

Comment: I'm unable to make it working...as you suggested I swapped `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` with `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` and I have replaced all my `if(strtoupper($paypalResponse["ACK"]) == "SUCCESS") {` ...now if I make a payment, it seems working but when on successful page on my website there is a bootstrap popup warning with nothing inside. And the account is not upgraded to pro. (good thing since the payment wasn't done)

Comment: @Simone Are you waiting until the customer comes back from PayPal before running `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` and the rest?

Comment: I just swapped the position of `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` with `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` keeping everything else of my code the same as I posted above. Also the empty warning message is shown only on success page, and so after the PayPal page

Comment: @Simone Then you missed my larger point. You cannot call GECD or DEC until **after** the user returns from PayPal. You need those two calls to be in a separate block testing for `if(isset($_GET['TOKEN']))`. Your call structure is wrong on that front.

Comment: I got this answer from the coder who makes this PayPal integration "The API calls are being done as per the PayPal's documentation, there's nothing wrong with them, I assume is something related with your PayPal live account.

P.S. The DEC is being done when the user returns on site as per the PayPal's documentation, otherwise it could have never store the user's information in the database in the first place."